# when opening two wpf application with transparancy="true" on 1 computer, only one shows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

we created two applications in wpf with transparency, when opening both the application on one computer the second app won't show, in taskbar you can see it running. If i disable the transparency in one app they are both shown.
Anyone ever had this problem and know how to fix this.

I have tried to set the parameters in the window properties and outside the window properties.

AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"

OR

```
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF111111" Opacity="0.1"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried this code on my side by using visual studio 2017. It works well and  when  both the application on one computer will show(Make sure the content of the form is different).

```
AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None"
```

Or:

```
<Window.Background>
<SolidColorBrush Color="#FF111111" Opacity="0.1"/>
```

I suggest you check it in the visual studio 2017. If it is work in visual studio 2017. You may can go to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/61/index.html) and report this issue at node NET or Visual Studio.